# Generate random date within one year and assign to var

Tags: javascript, date

How would I code this:

var randomDate = some random date between 01/01/2015 and 12/31/2015 formatted in mm/dd/yyyy;

alert(randomDate);

Answer (score 4):

Try this you need jquery UI as well with this solution:

```
function randomDate(start, end) {
  var date = new Date(+start + Math.random() * (end - start));
  return date;
}
var date1 = new Date(2013,09,01);
var date2 = new Date(2013,09,20);
alert($.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy",randomDate(date1, date2)));
```

Updated JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/f5q91cxn/2/

Comment: this works but returns the loooooong date: Sat Jul 19 2014 23:53:35 GMT-0700 (PDT)" — how can I format it to mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: @KirkRoss, please read about methods associated with the javascript Date object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @KirkRoss take a look: [updated version of this function](http://jsfiddle.net/t94778xt/)

Comment: See the update i just added. This should do it for you but you need jquery UI as well.